# elasticsearch 7.3 "field expansion matches too many fields"

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql

I have an elastic instance with an index with about 65k records. Each document is not what I would call large. I have tried to make as many of the fields as possible mapped and as many as can be are KEYWORD datatype. Currently not having issues with POST queries but any uri query such as "?q=slug:example-slug" throws this error:

```
  failed_shards: [{
    shard: 0,
    index: "items",
    node: "FC4TMXu1RxCOBGM8nUhsVw",
    reason: {
        type: "query_shard_exception",
        reason: "failed to create query: { "
        query_string " : { "
        query " : "
        slug: example-slug ", "
        fields " : [ ], "
        type " : "
        best_fields ", "
        default_operator " : "
        or ", "
        max_determinized_states " : 10000, "
        enable_position_increments " : true, "
        fuzziness " : "
        AUTO ", "
        fuzzy_prefix_length " : 0, "
        fuzzy_max_expansions " : 50, "
        phrase_slop " : 0, "
        analyze_wildcard " : false, "
        escape " : false, "
        auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query " : true, "
        fuzzy_transpositions " : true, "
        boost " : 1.0 } }",
        index_uuid: "sXQAz8gzRKmXXXmZn8j7Rw",
        index: "items",
        caused_by: {
            type: "illegal_argument_exception",
            reason: "field expansion matches too many fields, limit: 1024, got: 1093"
        }
    }
}]
```

I know that there is a .yml edit I can make to allow more clauses but I'm hesitant to do that due to the performance warnings on the elastic docs.... mostly I'm not understanding why this uri query causes this, especially since there's only ONE field called slug, and its a keyword. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Change index.query.default_field  in your settings.

Comment: @LeBigCat if you want to put this as an answer i will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change index.query.default_field in your settings.

Comment: Change it to what exactly? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking-changes-7.0.html#_limiting_the_number_of_auto_expanded_fields

> Executing queries that use automatic expansion of fields (e.g.
> query_string, simple_query_string or multi_match) can have performance
> issues for indices with a large numbers of fields. To safeguard
> against this, a default limit of 1024 fields has been introduced for
> queries using the "all fields" mode ("default_field": "*") or other
> fieldname expansions (e.g. "foo*").
> If needed, you can change this
> limit using the  dynamic cluster
> setting.

Note: `indices.query.bool.max_clause_count` needs to be updated in elasticsearch.yml

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue in AWS ELK service, I update it from the AWS console.

- Select domain
- Edit domain
- Advance option
- Max clause count

[image]